What is the geometry of space-time in a uniformly accelerated frame?
I know a uniformly accelerated frame can be equivalently considered to be in a uniform/homogeneous gravitational field.But is the space-time in such a frame "flat"(Minkowskian) or curved? Or can it be analyzed either way? And if it is curved, or may be optionally treated as such,what is the nature of the curvature? Extrinsic or intrinsic? Constant or variable? I think this is a simple little question for those who know the subject and can be answered by them without bringing in much mathematical formalism.

Hint: The Riemann tensor is a tensor; it does not change whether you use Rindler or Minkowski coordinates.

Regarding your premise, it's important to understand also that a homogeneous gravitational field, which implies a homogeneous curvature is unphysical and as far as we know not possible in nature. This also gives you a lead on how to think about the difference from a uniformly accelerated frame.

@JeanbaptisteRoux That appears to be an answer, not a comment, please consider making it an answer.

@ACuriousMind I'm afraid I have to disagree. This is an answer only if you already know it is. You see it as an answer because you're a beast (this is a compliment), and so of course you know it is. But for someone who might struggle with the notion of tensor, as the OP, this is more of a hint.

A uniformly accelerated frame is equivalent to a uniform gravitational field only in its infinitesimal neighborhood, and this is flat.

Not true. In a uniformly accelerated frame the grav. field is uniform everywhere. Only no such grav field exists in nature. Real grav fields are all non-uniform, approaching uniformity only locally.
